# Does the best decision in a card game depend on wether someone shuffles the cards or not. (Black Jack)

Tags: probability, logic

When playing Black Jack a friend of mine (he was the person to sit directly before the bank so after his turn it's the banks turn) said that the fact that the card he would take or take not is the card the bank would get if he doesn't take the card influences the decision he should make.

I guess the exact situation was the following: He had 12 points and the bank had a 10 and since the most likely card is the 10 (or King, Queen, Jack) he was arguing: If the card in the stack is a ten then he will lose this game if he takes the card or not, if it is a 9 then I should take the card and the same with 8, 7, 6 and so on. I replied that this might be the right decision (I know there are tables that show what to do in each situation) but the argumentation is wrong because the decision is independent of wether the card is already chosen or not.

In other words: I think the situation would be the same when someone shuffles the cards before the bank takes one and my friend said there is a difference (so this is not about what to do in Black Jack but it is about wether this makes a difference).

Or in another words: Does the player that sit before the bank have to make other decisions than the other players?

I tried to convince my friend by telling him this example: Let's assume the stack of cards is a black box and I don't know how it works (wether it shuffles the cards or not) then I wouldn't have any change to figure out how it works because the outcome is the same. But this example wasn't convincing for my friend at all, so the question is: Is he right and if not, ho to convince him?

Comment: Do you *see* what the bank takes?  Then that affects what you know to calculate the odds.  And your probabilities are different.  If you don't it has no effect on you calculation.  Bear in mind probability is not the degree to which something is likely to happen (either it will or it won't 100% or 0%) but the accuracy to which you are able to predict.  Additional information changes your ability to calculate accurately.  Even after all the cards are dealt.

Comment: Okay, I think what your friend is saying is he calculates whether a card is say a six and calculates that if he thinks it is a six whether he should take it or not and takes into effect if he doesn't the next player or the dealer will.  So he calculates the benefit of his taking it vs the person on the left.  If it's only up to him and if he refuses it, it is gone, and the deck is reshuffled, that is a different situation.